# Скриншот экрана устройства

Tags: java, android, appium

Сделать скриншот экрана устройства и сохранить по установленному пути.

Ранее была использована библиотека для этого случая. Сейчас не могу вспомнить какая именно.

Реализованный код:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\jobs\\KBL\\screenshots\\Samsung_a3\\" + outprint + "(" + ("q") + ").png"));
```

FileUtil просит создать новый метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимая библиотека: Apache Commons IO.

Код:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\Test\\22.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        report("Ошибка, не удалось сделать скрин");
    }
```